# Wordpress Query Not Working - No Error - Query Fine otherwise

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a $wpdb query I'm trying to execute, but it's not going through and is throwing no error:

```
$followups = 
    $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM orders 
                WHERE status_id = %d
                AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_waiting_pickup) % 7 = %d",
                array(66, 0)
            )
        );
```

Any idea why?  It runs fine in Terminal / direct MySQL.  Is it the `DIFFDATE()` function?

EDIT:  And interestingly enough, if I remove the `$wpdb->prepare` function, and leave `$wpdb->get_results()`, it works fine.  So is there something I'm missing as far as how `$wpdb->prepare()` works?

Comment: +1 for the PHP code formating!

Comment: You meant `DATEDIFF()` DATEDIFF() is a legal mysql function, np in that part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that you want, as it seems, orders <s>in the last week</s>... Why don't you simplify it? There is no need for the second `%d` just put 0.

```
$followups = 
    $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM orders 
                WHERE status_id = %d
                AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_waiting_pickup) % 7 = 0",
                66
            )
        );
```

**UPDATE**:

@dtj You are using `mod` (%) operator that give us the remainder of the division. So comparing with `0` (my first assumption) we obtain orders from today, 1 week ago, 2 week ago, etc.. If we compare with 1 (in the second `%d`) we obtain orders form yesterday, 8 days ago, etc...

Is really that what you want?

**UPDATE 2**: In your edited question you say that removing `$wpdb->prepare()` all works fine. No doubt is interesting, but fortunately you really don't need `prepare()` if you just works with integer numbers. I mean doing:

```
$status_id = (int) (is_numeric($status_id) ? $status_id : 0);

$followups = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * FROM orders
    WHERE status_id = $status_id
    AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_waiting_pickup) % 7 = 0");
```

you assure a safe query and gain in simplicity and efficiency. In my case I only use `prepare()` if there are `strings` involved and always test integer numbers as showed.

Comment: Yes, 1 weeks, 2 weeks, etc..  But for whatever reason, $wpdb is not processing this Query.  If I remove diffdate(), it works fine

Comment: @dtj So periods of weeks: 1, 2, etc. yes, it make sense. I give you a recommendation in my last update. Good luck! 8)

Comment: Fair enough.  Still curious why it didn't work though with prepare.  Seems odd.  But thanks!

Comment: It's odd. But is Saturday and the beers are cold... Cheers mate.